# Salary change when going from developer to hired consultant?

Tags: software-industry, salary

I am currently employed at a company as a mobile platforms developer. Just recently I have been asked by HR if I want to be a work as hired consultant at a clients headquarters 6 hours away for a undefined amount of time.

The developers at the clients place has roughly a 50% higher salary than my own.
I am already underpaid in terms of my knowledge and current employers location.
Am in the wrong to ask for a raise before accepting?

Comment: Have you thought about going to work as a consultant for a while there until they get to know you, then asking for a job there where you'll get the better salary?

Comment: @2rs2ts the thought has crossed my mind, but i am not fully interested in moving there permanently.

Comment: Is their higher salary range related to the location?

Comment: @cdkMoose yes that is correct, understandable as it is a larger city.
Even in my current location my salary is below the average.

Comment: do you mean a self employed consultant? if so a good rule of thumb is 3x your rate as a full time employee

Comment: It might be reasonable to request a short term bump for  the length of the assignment, but not permanently

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 5):

> Am in the wrong to ask for a raise before accepting?

Not at all.

If you are asked to work that far away, it's perfectly reasonable to ask if/how you will be compensated.

On the other hand, if you will get such a raise probably depends on their needs and the leverage you have.

Make sure you ask about and thoroughly understand anything else that might change if you accept - benefits, accruals, tax status, housing allowance, travel expenses, etc.